# If confirm in js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I need something like this to work:

Show.erb.js:

```
if (confirm('Delete cart?')) { 
  <%@current_cart.reset%>
  $('.cartbadge').replaceWith('<%= j render :partial => "layouts/cartbadge"%>');
}
```

but the erb portion of the code is always excecuting

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the code `<%@current_cart.reset%>` will be executed when the erb be interpretered.

You have to use ajax like:

```
if (confirm('Delete cart?')) { 
  $.post('<%= reset_cart_path(@current_cart) %>', function() {
      $('.cartbadge').replaceWith('<%= j render :partial => "layouts/cartbadge"%>');
  });
}
```